# Kafka Broker ID in Java

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

I want to know is there a way to set the broker ID for Kafka in Java?

I can see there is `broker.id` configuration parameter in `server.properties` to configure broker ID, but I want this to be overridden during run time by picking the broker ID from a configuration file from each broker node.

Comment: once the broker is started the broker id can't be changed at runtime

Comment: As per my need, Broker ID won't be changed during runtime. But I don't want to pick the broker ID from server.properties. Rather I would like to pick it up programmatically from a master configuration file within my system.

Comment: for that case , you will have to write some program which will create or update server.properties and pass it on to the broker startup script

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Are you trying to connect to a different broker from within your Kafka program? Or you really want to programatically change the id of a running Kafka broker?

Comment: As @LijuJohn highlighted, we have decided to update the server.properties file to update the broker.id before starting the broker.